# Error while catching returned value from contract

Tags: contract-deployment, testrpc, web3.py

I am trying to set a string and receive it back from my contract.

This is my code

```
    import web3
import json

from web3 import Web3
def main():
    w3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider("http://localhost:8545"))
    w3.eth.defaultAccount = w3.eth.accounts[0]
    print(w3.eth.defaultAccount)
    with open('abi', 'r') as abi_definition:
        abi = json.load(abi_definition)
    contract = w3.eth.contract(address=w3.toChecksumAddress('0x82A978B3f5962A5b0957d9ee9eEf472EE55B42F1'),abi=abi)
    contract.constructor().transact()
    contract.functions.storeID('yes').call()
    get = contract.functions.getID().call()
    print(get)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I am getting following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sapan/PycharmProjects/GlobalCA/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/web3/contract.py", line 1214, in call_contract_function
    output_data = decode_abi(output_types, return_data)
  File "/home/sapan/PycharmProjects/GlobalCA/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/eth_abi/abi.py", line 63, in decode_abi
    return decoder(stream)
  File "/home/sapan/PycharmProjects/GlobalCA/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/eth_abi/decoding.py", line 99, in __call__
    return self.decode(stream)
  File "/home/sapan/PycharmProjects/GlobalCA/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/eth_utils/functional.py", line 22, in inner
    return callback(fn(*args, **kwargs))
  File "/home/sapan/PycharmProjects/GlobalCA/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/eth_abi/decoding.py", line 135, in decode
    yield HeadTailDecoder.as_decoder(tail_decoder=decoder)(stream)
  File "/home/sapan/PycharmProjects/GlobalCA/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/eth_abi/decoding.py", line 99, in __call__
    return self.decode(stream)
  File "/home/sapan/PycharmProjects/GlobalCA/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/eth_abi/decoding.py", line 113, in decode
    start_pos = decode_uint_256(stream)
  File "/home/sapan/PycharmProjects/GlobalCA/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/eth_abi/decoding.py", line 99, in __call__
    return self.decode(stream)
  File "/home/sapan/PycharmProjects/GlobalCA/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/eth_abi/decoding.py", line 162, in decode
    raw_data = cls.read_data_from_stream(stream)
  File "/home/sapan/PycharmProjects/GlobalCA/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/eth_abi/decoding.py", line 244, in read_data_from_stream
    len(data),
eth_abi.exceptions.InsufficientDataBytes: Tried to read 32 bytes.  Only got 0 bytes

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sapan/PycharmProjects/GlobalCA/Node.py", line 18, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/sapan/PycharmProjects/GlobalCA/Node.py", line 14, in main
    get = contract.functions.getID().call()
  File "/home/sapan/PycharmProjects/GlobalCA/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/web3/contract.py", line 979, in call
    **self.kwargs)
  File "/home/sapan/PycharmProjects/GlobalCA/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/web3/contract.py", line 1236, in call_contract_function
    raise BadFunctionCallOutput(msg) from e
web3.exceptions.BadFunctionCallOutput: Could not transact with/call contract function, is contract deployed correctly and chain synced?
```

Comment: The code you shared doesn't include the line of code in the stack trace.

Comment: Sorry, I was messing around with the code previously. I edited it now. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This line might be wrong:

```
contract.functions.storeID('yes').call()
```

if you're changing the status, as the name suggest, it should be

```
contract.functions.storeID('yes').transact()
```

Comment: Thanks that did solve the issue. Can I also view the value returned in python ?

Comment: transactions usually return a transaction hash than can be used to retrieve the transaction information and the receipt